Congruent vertices are equidistance from the center of a Dirichlet Domain for a Fuchsian group
Let $D_x(G)$ be a Dirichlet domain for a Fuchsian group $G$, where x is the center of the Dirichlet domain then show that $d(x,z_1)=d(x,z_2) $ where $z_1,z_2$ are congruent vertices of the Dirichlet domain . Here distance means Hyperbolic distance .
Proof: Consider $z_1$ and $z_2$ on the boundary of $D_x(G)$ with $z_2= h(z_1)$. As the geodesic $[x, z_1)\in  D_x(G)$ we see that $[hx, z_2) = h[x, z_1) \subset h(D_x(G)) = D_{hx}(G)$.
It follows that $z_2$ is equidistant from $x$ and $hx$ and so $d(x, z_2) = d(hx, z_2) = d(x, h^{-1}z_2)=d(x,Z_1).$
My doubt is  why $z_2$ is in equidistant from both $x,h(x)$?
